# Gesture Recognizer does not work. The action of the element that is underneath is performed - SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Gesture Recognizer does not work.

The action of the element that is underneath is performed.

I added UIView to the TabBarController.

If I click on the created UIView, the action of the element that is under it is executed.

```
class func createSpeechView(tabBar: UITabBarController)
    {

        let speech = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Speech", owner: Bundle.main, options: nil)![0] as! SpeechView

        tabBar.tabBar.addSubview(speech)
        speech.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        speech.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.tabBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        speech.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.tabBar.topAnchor, constant: -(height + 10)).isActive = true
        speech.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.tabBar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -30).isActive = true
        speech.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true

        speech.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        speech.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: tabBar, action: #selector(tapGesture)))

    }

    @objc class func tapGesture()
    {
        print("tap")
    }
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: use UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
speech.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: tabBar, action: #selector(tapGesture)))
```

with

```
speech.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: tabBar, action: #selector(tapGesture)))
```